# RewriteRule :page not found when name is "index"

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Im trying to redirect any page calls to public/index.php?_url=calls

I have this in var/www/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule  ^$ public/    [L]
    RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

in /var/www/public/.htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

When i enter to http://mywebsite.com/something/anotherthing works ok, redirect to public/index.php?_url=something/anotherthing , but, when i tried with http://mywebsite.com/index/something shows not found error.

Any idea to solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because this check:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

takes into account "path info", which means: `/index/something` "exists" and thus passes the `-f` check.

Additoinally, you need to turn off multiviews:

```
Options -Multiviews
```

Comment: You help me to fix it and explained the reason, thanks bro. I can select your answer as accepted in 5 minutes. Again, thanks.